# How can the Windows Command Line do a grep -o?

Tags: windows, command-line, grep

Is there a way in Windows to get a matching string within a string?

```
echo hereisastring | find "is"  and just display is
```

without using grep

The following worked using FIND.  credit to Hello71

```
C:\>echo abcd | find "bc" >nul && if errorlevel 0 echo bc
bc

C:\>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ECHO %STRING% | FIND "%FIND%"
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO %FIND%
```

Comment: C:\test>echo abcd | find "bc" if errorlevel 0 echo "bc"  <-- doesn't seem to work. Does this have to be multiple lines? does it have to use environment variables?

Comment: Can you give a full working example?  I don't really understand why at one point you've put an environment variable in quotations and in another point not.

Comment: @barlop: You need to use && to separate commands in Command Prompt. `FIND` requires its parameter to be in quotes.

Comment: @Hello71 I couldn't get the example with environment variables to work because set is a bit funny, putting spaces or new lines in.  Have you managed to get it to work with environment variables?  I did get it working without though.

Comment: @barlop: The environment variables were for the purpose of the example.

Comment: @Hello71 So are you able to get it working using environment variables?

Comment: @barlop: No, the code was untested.

Comment: accepted since it was pretty much there.